# convert .nl image file

Tags: image, batch-processing

I have a list of hundreds of hyperlinks that are to image files from my supplier.  The problem is they have a .nl file extension.  Here's an example:

http://www.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=66821&c=ACCT120207&h=bad4512e36320e5b2239

I need to use some sort of batch process to find all those image files and convert them to a .png or .jpg link (or batch download all the images then rename them)

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your link doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Sorry, try this  https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=101065&c=ACCT120207&h=ff667401c82a7dc4c2e1

Answer (score 0):

As you don't show an excerpt from your list of URLs, nor state your Operating System, it is rather hard to help you process the entire list.

However, for the one URL you show, you can retrieve the image and store it locally as `"image.jpg"` like this:

```
curl -L "https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=101065&c=ACCT120207&h=ff667401c82a7dc4c2e1" > image.jpg
```